# In my Java merge sort fucntion, even when the condition is false, it is entering the loop. Why?

Tags: java, merge, mergesort

In my "merge" function, in the while loop, the given condition is `a!=null && b!=null`, but when `b` is null, it still enters the while loop and then later gives an error.

```
int[] merge(int[]a, int[]b)
{
    int length = a.length+b.length;
    int[]c = new int[length];
    while (a!=null && b!=null)
    {
        if (a[0]<b[0])
        {
            c[length-1]=a[0];
            a = tail(a);
        }
        else
        {
            c[length-1]=b[0];
            b = tail(b);
        }
    }
    return c;
}

int[] mergeSort(int[]a)
{
    if (a.length==1)
        return a;

    int[] q = new int[a.length];
    int[] l = new int[a.length/2];
    int [] r = new int[a.length-l.length];

    for (int i=0; i<l.length; i++)
    {
        l[i] = a[i];
    }
    for (int i=l.length; i<r.length; i++)
    {
        r[i-l.length] = a[i];
    }
    q = merge(mergeSort(l), mergeSort(r));
    return q;
}
```

Comment: code seems to be correct. how do you know `b` is null? what error do you get and why is it "later"?

Comment: a is the arr a[i] is index in the arr, if the arr size is 0 a!=null but a[0] give an error

Comment: what is the error that you get ?

Comment: "java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:
0"

This is the error I'm getting while running the code! Thanks

Comment: you need a!=null&&a.size()>0&&b!=nulll&&b.size()>0

Comment: @Kushal Chachan In the answer there is pseudo-code of `merge` function. Basically, you should take into account that one of arrays (either `a` or `b`) might be empty during or before merge. So you need to change conditions and update logic correspondingly.

Comment: What is your `tail()` method?  What is it supposed to return with a one-element array, an empty array or `null`? Also, in `merge()` why do you put everything in the last element of `c` ?

Comment: @MichelBillaud `tail()` method returns an empty array with a one-element array. I am putting everything at end of `c` so that the sorted array is in descending order.

Comment: @Kushal Chachan actually your putting everything in the last position of c, not from the last position to the first. c is not "growing". Please run your program on small examples, like the [20, 10] array. - if empty array, why do you test against null ( no array)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, you're facing situation when one of array (either `a` or `b`) is already empty, and the other one - still has elements. So, in the `merge` function you should take this into account.

This is full implementation of your `mergeSort`:

```
public class Answer {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] unsorted = new int[]{4,3,4,2,1,1,3,3,3,3,3,5,6,6,9,9,10,7,7,8};
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(mergeSort(unsorted)));
  }

  public static int[] mergeSort(int[]a) {
    if (a.length == 1) return a;

    int[] q = new int[a.length];
    int[] l = new int[a.length / 2];
    int [] r = new int[a.length - l.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < l.length; i++) {
      l[i] = a[i];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < r.length; i++) {
      r[i] = a[l.length + i];
    }

    q = merge(mergeSort(l), mergeSort(r));
    return q;
  }

  private static int[] merge(int[]a, int[]b) {
    int length = a.length + b.length;
    int[] c = new int[length];
    int p = 0;
    while (a.length > 0 && b.length > 0) {
      if (a[0] < b[0]) {
        c[p++] = a[0];
        a = tail(a);
      } else {
        c[p++] = b[0];
        b = tail(b);
      }
    }
    while (a.length > 0) {
       c[p++] = a[0];
       a = tail(a);
    }
    while (b.length > 0) {
       c[p++] = b[0];
       b = tail(b);
    }
    return c;
  }

  private static int[] tail(int[] a) {
    int[] t = new int[a.length - 1];
    for (int i = 0; i < t.length; i++) {
      t[i] = a[i + 1];
    }
    return t;
  }
}
```

Comment: Did the same thing but still doesn't work. This time it doesn't give any error but returns an unsorted list in some other order.

Comment: @KushalChachan I've updated the answer with actual code. `merge` method should be fine now. If you still having problems  - then `mergeSort` method has some issues.

Comment: I did the same thing, thanks for your help. I guess there's some problem with `mergeSort`.

Comment: Pseudo code for `mergeSort`:

if length of A is 1:
return A.

Split A into two lists, l and r.

q = merge(mergeSort(l),mergeSort(r)).

return q.

Comment: @KushalChachan You had problem in this part `for (int i=l.length; i<r.length;i++)  {        r[i-l.length] = a[i]; }` of `mergeSort`. I've updated the answer with full solution.

Comment: @KushalChachan Your `mergeSort` implementation should work fine now. However, using `tail` method adds additional operations. So, implementation can be optimized further by removing `tail` and using pointers to positions in the array.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you have a problem with the auxiliary method `merge()`.

I strongly recommend you to take this as an opportunity to practice systematic testing of your methods. Consider that we all constantly make mistakes when we write programs, and spotting errors to correct them is a real part of the job.

What make it easier, is to anticipate over this matter of fact : sh*t happens. And take time to write down some test cases, with input data and expected results.

```
int[] empty = {};
int [] r1 = merge(empty, empty);
System.out.println("Result should be empty\n");
printArray(r1);

int [] oneElement = { 23 };
int [] r3 = merge(oneElement, empty);
System.out.println("Result should be [23]\n");
printArray(r2);

...
```

So you have automated tests (we're all too lazy to do it by hand every time after the 35th modification of the code°.

This will lead you to "unit tests"....